# Android: Not able to connect to internet during phone call on mobile via providers network

Tags: android, phone-call, connectivity

I have written an android application which connects to a remote server using HttpClient whenever there is a phone call. This is done to log the call information in the server. The server sends a response which is  displayed as a toast to the user. All this (should) take place before the user picks up the phone. I have also set the connection timeout. Code to connect the server is written as a IntentService.

Now this work perfectly fine on the emulator and on the mobile when the user is connected to the internet over wifi but if he is connected via the providers network (3G) the communication with the server takes place only after the user hangs up [the popup is displayed after the user hangs up].

Tested it on : HTC - Sprint

I would like to know if this behavior is because of the providers network / mobile phone or is it an issue of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Sprint's 3G network (EVDO) does not allow simultaneous data and voice connections.

The networks that do allow voice + data are:

- 4G (LTE)
- 4G (Wimax)
- HSPA+ (AT&T)